# All pictures upload by users need to be able to be auto resize in opencart

Tags: opencart

All pictures upload by users need to be able to be auto resize (like Facebook for the personal profile photo where it will make it smaller and you can drag to fit) in opencart

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you have code that you've tried to do what you want and it has a problem?

Comment: actully it's ecommerce site but user can upload there oun products . what is need is some how resize the picture uploaded by user and make it smaller and also able to drag it to fit like in  facebook , but sir i have all the core understanding of php but i am new to opencart and cvm-l concept :( , i know i can do this but pls sir help me !! :(

Comment: What is *cvm-l* concept? Never heard of it... But I am pretty sure OC does not use any *cvm-l* concept...

Comment: Model–view–controller (MVC) and l for language .. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to admin.
2. Go to `System > Settings > Image` tab.
3. Scroll down to see the image sizes mentioned and update it as per your requirements.

For resizing your own new images, you can use the below code:

```
$this->load->model('tool/image'); 
$user_image_resized = $this->model_tool_image->resize($user_image, $resize_width, $resize_height);  
//$user_image - user image file name with path relative to `image` folder
//$resize_width - the image width needed
//$resize_height - the image height needed
```

Have a nice day :)  !!

Comment: but sir from there i can only adjust the product images uploaded by site admin . but in site i am working i need to resize picture uploaded by user ....!!

Comment: Though the code is correct I doubt the OP will now where to put it. I bet he has some custom modification or extension that he is not orientating within...

Comment: You're correct, but with the given info i think i cannot help him more. He said that he has got php experience,  so sometimes this will be enough to help him.

Comment: thnx sir i will let you know when this thing start working !!